# Elixir command line app with list as parameter

Tags: list, elixir

i'm building a simple CLI app with elixir using the following code as my parse function

```
def parse_args(args) do
 options = OptionParser.parse(args)

 case options do
   {[list: list], _, _} -> [list]
   _ -> :help
 end
end
```

calling the app with

```
./app --list one,two,three
```

my problem is how to convert comma separated string (binary) into list or any better way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can either split using `String.split/2`:

```
iex(1)> {[list: list], _, _} = OptionParser.parse(["--list", "one,two,three"])
{[list: "one,two,three"], [], []}
iex(2)> String.split(list, ",")
["one", "two", "three"]
```

or use the `strict: [list: :keep]` option and pass the arguments as `./app --list one --list two --list three`:

```
iex(1)> {parsed, _, _} = OptionParser.parse(["--list", "one", "--list", "two", "--list", "three"], strict: [list: :keep])
{[list: "one", list: "two", list: "three"], [], []}
iex(2)> Keyword.get_values(parsed, :list)
["one", "two", "three"]
```

I would use the first one unless your strings can contain a comma (in that case you could use another delimiter).